# Rendering Twig template with SwiftMailer

Tags: symfony, outlook, twig, swiftmailer

I'm working on sendmail automation with Symfony, I mainly use the  SwiftMailer service to send emails and twig for templates  mail.
I have a problem when I open the email with mail client Gmail, it has the right format.
but when I open it with **outlook ,the text appears offbeat and sometimes blocks appear superimposed.**

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this problem .thx

Comment: Are you sure this is actually caused by the *producing component* (swiftmailer/twig)? Maybe it's an outlook thing, and you would need to check the final html to be suitable to be used with outlook.

Comment: frankly I do not know exactly where the error is coming! by cons if I open the mail with the mail client "Gmail" whether on the PC or mobile, it appears as it is supposed to be displayed! and when I open it with Outlook mail client is malformed :s

Comment: To debug this, try sending a handcrafter html-mail and tweak the html until it works with outlook. Use this then as your template for twig.

Comment: The available `HTML` in e-mails is limited by the client it's receives. It is possible that outlook just does not support the feature u want and u'll need to work around it

Answer (score 0):

Develop email is very headlock...Lot of think for differents client messaging support etc...

You can read this excellent topic for more understand all concept of this :
[develop email correctly](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/design-and-build-an-email-newsletter-without-losing-your-mind/)